# Dynamically changing the size of an array and reading in values. (w/o vectors)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

Hello I am having the following difficulty,
I am trying to read in a table of doubles (1 entry per line) and store it in an array, while dynamically changing this array's size (for each line/entry). This is for a school assignment and **it forbids the use of vectors**(would be much easier...). The main idea that I had is to have a main array which stores the value, then store the previous values and the next one into a new array and do this iteratively. Currently, the problem that I am having is that only the last value of the table is being stored. I am aware, that somehow I need to be passing the data by refference to the global function and that the pointers that I am working with become null ater they exit the following iteration of the while. However, since the exact length of the data is unknown, this seems impossible since intializing an array in the main() is impossible (exact length not known). Any help would be appreciated.
Code posted below.

EDIT: after consideration of the two comments I made the following changes to the code, however I am not sure, whether they will behave appropriately. I added a new function called `add_new_datapoint`, that should globally change the values of the  pointer/length and this is done by passing the values by refference. Called in the problematic else statement as add_new_datapoint(data_ptr, data_len, new_dp). Also, I am not sure that reallocating new memory to the pointer variable, will not result in a memory leak. In essence (after I reallocate `data_ptr` is the memory that was 'being pointed to' released or do I have to delete it and then re-inialise it in the . In such case, can I refference the pointer 'data_ptr' again in the next iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be easier to simplify your posted code than trying to find all the places where you could have errors.

If you expect to see only `double` values in your file, you can simplify the code for reading data from the file to:

```
while ( data_file >> new_data_pt )
{
   // Use new_data_pt
}
```

If you expect that there might be values other than  `double`s, then you can use:

```
while ( getline(data_file, line) )
{
    std::istringstream str(line);
    while ( str >> new_data_pt )
    {
       // Use new_data_pt
    }
}
```

but then you have to understand the code will not read any more values from a line after it encounters an error. If your line contains

```
10.2 K 25.4
```

the code will read `10.2`, encounter an error at `K`, and will not process `25.4`.

The code to process `new_data_pt` is that it needs to be stored in a dynamically allocated array. I would suggest putting that in a function.

```
double* add_point(double* data_ptr, int data_len, double new_data_pt)
```

Call that function as:

```
data_ptr = add_point(data_ptr, data_len, new_data_pt);
```

Assuming the first `while` loop, the contents of `main` become:

```
int main()
{   
   std::fstream data_file{ "millikan2.dat" };

   // It is possible that the file has nothing in it.
   // In that case, data_len needs to be zero.
   int data_len{ 0 };

   // There is no need to allocate memory when there is nothing in the file.
   // Allocate memory only when data_len is greater than zero.
   double* data_ptr = nullptr; 

   double new_data_pt;

   if (!data_file.good()) {
      std::cerr << "Cannot open file";
      return 1;
   }

   while ( data_file >> new_data_pt ) 
   {
      ++data_len;
      data_ptr = add_point(data_ptr, data_len, new_data_pt);
   }

   // No need of this.
   // The file will be closed when the function returns.
   // data_file.close();
}
```

`add_point` can be implemented as:

```
 double* add_point(double* data_ptr, int data_len, double new_data_pt)
 {
    double* new_data_ptr = new double[data_len];

    // This works even when data_ptr is nullptr.
    // When data_ptr is null_ptr, (data_len - 1) is zero. Hence,
    // the call to std::copy becomes a noop.
    std::copy(data_ptr, data_ptr + (data_len - 1); new_data_ptr);

    // Deallocate old memory.
    if ( data_ptr != nullptr )
    {
       delete [] data_ptr;
    }

    new_data_ptr[data_len-1] = new_data_pt;
    return new_data_ptr;
 }
```

The code to track the number of bad points is a lot more complex. Unless you are required to do it, I would advise to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You already got an excellent answer but I figured it may be helpful to point out a few mistakes in your code, so you can understand why it won't work.

In the second else scope you declare `data_ptr` again, even though it is visible from the outer scope. (`delete[]` doesn't delete the pointer itself, it just deallocates the memory the pointer points to.)

```
else {
            double* data_temp { new double[data_len] };
            std::copy(data_ptr, data_ptr + data_len - 2, data_temp);
            *(data_temp + data_len - 1) = new_data_pt;
            delete[] data_ptr;
            double* data_ptr{ new double[data_len] }; // <- Right here
            //for (int j{1}; j < data_len; j++) *(data_ptr + j) = *(data_temp + j);
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
```

Instead you could just write `data_ptr = new double[data_len]`. However, that alone won't make this work.

All of your data disappears because on every iteration you create a new array, pointed to by `data_temp` and copy the data there, and on the next iteration you set `data_temp` to point to a new array again. This means that on every iteration you lose all data from previous iterations. This also causes a memory leak, since you allocate more memory every time you hit this line:

`double* data_temp { new double[data_len] };`

but you don't call `delete[] data_temp` afterwards.

I hope this helps to understand why it doesn't work.